# Можно ли в git посмотреть историю изменений одного файла?

Tags: git, git-log

Хотелось бы такую фичу:

```
11.05.2017 14:22:02
Строка: ...
Было: ...
Стало: ...
```

Comment: При чем тут javascript?

Comment: @Kromster Вы о JS-Git?

Comment: Я о том, что было бы хорошо уточнить среду в которой вы хотите увидеть решение вопроса (консоль git, клиент под Windows или Linux, браузер, гитхаб?)

Comment: @Kromster только консоль, остальное не нужно )))

Answer (score 5):

Можно.

```
git log -p -- path/filename.txt
```

Подробнее:

- Параметр `-p` нужен для того, чтобы `git log` показал построчный дифф.
- `--` отделяет параметры от передаваемых путей к файлам. После `--` — только пути.
- `path/filename.txt` – путь к файлу, историю изменений которого вы хотите посмотреть.

Comment: Немного лучше `git whatchanged --stat -p -M -C -D -- patch/to/filename.txt`.

Comment: @0andriy ага! Завтра попробую. Я смутно помнил про whatchanged, но гуглить не стал. :)

Comment: Всё то же самое можно и в `git log` подать. "Немного лучше" заключается в ежедневном использовании *вместо* `git log`.